# Return a value from vbscript function in c#

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, vbscript

I am executing a .vbs file from my code in c# for checking the authenticity of user. I am passing username and password values and on login click .vbs will run and authenticate the user. If the user in not authentic then function in vbs returns a value, how can i get that value in my code in c# and use it to display proper error message in UI of application.
Please help..

Comment: How are you run VBS? Can you explain some code to clarify?

Comment: Process.Start("Execute.vbs"); I am executing the vbs file. What i need now is to pass values of uname and pwd from winform UI to function in Execute and that function will return a string value which i have to display it in UI again.

Answer (score 2):

Not to present production code, but to show

1. that/how it 'works in principle'
2. what keywords/components you have to look up in the docs

demo.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Demo
{
    public class Demo
    {
        public static void Main(string [] args) {
            string user  = "nix";
            if (1 <= args.Length) {user = args[0];};
            string passw = "nix";
            if (2 <= args.Length) {passw = args[1];};
            string cscript = "cscript";
            string cmd = string.Format("\"..\\vbs\\auth.vbs\" {0} {1}", user, passw);
            System.Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", cscript, cmd);

            Process process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            process.StartInfo.FileName = "cscript.exe";
            process.StartInfo.Arguments = cmd;
            try {
              process.Start();
              System.Console.WriteLine(process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
              System.Console.WriteLine(process.ExitCode);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
              System.Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

auth.vbs:

```
Option Explicit

Dim nRet : nRet = 2
If WScript.Arguments.Count = 2 Then
   If "user" = WScript.Arguments(0) And "passw" = WScript.Arguments(1) Then
      WScript.Echo "ok"
      nRet = 0
   Else
      WScript.Echo "fail"
      nRet = 1
   End If
Else
   WScript.Echo "bad"
End If
WScript.Quit nRet
```

output:

```
demo.exe
cscript "..\vbs\auth.vbs" nix nix
fail

1

demo.exe user passw
cscript "..\vbs\auth.vbs" user passw
ok

0
```

Perhaps you can simplify things by forgetting the text return and use the .Exitcode only.