# Read Exit Code from VBS Script through Process in C#

Tags: c#, vbscript, exit-code

I'm calling a VBS-Script from my C# Console Application using the `Process` class.

```
Process script = Process.Start("cscript", arguments);
script.WaitForExit()
int exitCode = script.ExitCode;
```

Now I want to be able to get feedback from the Script to tell if everything got through without problems.

I call the script using "`cscript //B //Nologo \Path\to\Script.vbs`" with the Process class. In my script, I want to be able to return feedback or raise some kind of error when a database entry is not found for example.

I found out that you can return error codes using `WScript.Quit(int)`

The problem is that `cscript` only seems to return something other than `0` when it can't find the file. If the file is found, Process.ExitCode is always `0` even when I use `WScript.Quit(1)` in the script.

Is there a way to get the exit code from the script or another way to communicate with the C# application?

Comment: No, the exit code of the script will always be what you pass to `WScript.Quit()`. If that doesn't seem to be working for you, then that means that line does not get executed in the script.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/14336151/603855. If that doesn't help, publish (relevant parts of) your cs/vbs code.

Comment: You can always pass messages back using standardoutput.

Comment: @Tomalak It seems that the //B was the problems. It seems to supress to returning of not-0 error code. When I switched to //I, it worked. But now it shows a msgbox that //B supressed before.

Comment: `//B` does **not** suppress the returning of the exit code.

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner True, but if I combine it have having a msgbox above the ´WScript.Quit(1)´, it skips the Quit if I have //B set.