# c# - Process.Start not giving any output for cscript/vbscript

Tags: c#, vbscript, output, process.start

I have been so lucky to get the task of making some old code ready for running on Server 2019 and what have always been working is now not working on Server 2019/Windows 10.

I am getting no output whatsoever from the vbscript.
Can somebody here please give me some tips, because it feels like I have tried almost everything...

Code to reproduce:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace VbsTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var vbs = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "test.vbs");
            if (!File.Exists(vbs))
            {
                File.WriteAllText(vbs, "Main\n\nSub Main\nWScript.Echo \"Test output\"\nEnd Sub");
            }

            string cScript = @"%SystemRoot%\System32\cscript.exe";
            string fullPath = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(cScript);

            var Arguments = " //u //nologo " + vbs;

            ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo()
            {
                FileName = fullPath,
                Arguments = Arguments,
                RedirectStandardError = true,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                CreateNoWindow = true, 
                WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden, 
                UseShellExecute = false 
            };

            var OutputMessages = "";
            DateTime scriptStart = DateTime.Now;
            Process MyProcess = new Process
            {
                StartInfo = psi,
                EnableRaisingEvents = true
            };

            MyProcess.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, e) =>
            {
                OutputMessages += e.Data + "\n";
            };

            MyProcess.OutputDataReceived += (sender, e) =>
            {
                OutputMessages += e.Data + "\n";
            };

            MyProcess.Start();
            MyProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();

            MyProcess.WaitForExit();

            Console.Write(OutputMessages);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try removing the `/u ` switch for cscript.exe

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Return a value from vbscript function in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14334403/return-a-value-from-vbscript-function-in-c-sharp).

Comment: You need to read from the processes [`StandardOutput`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput?view=net-5.0) stream reader property.